# En ASP:NET MVC 4 como mostrar cuantos registros se estan procesando al subir un archivo de Excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

tengo la siguiente duda y tal vez alguien ya lo haya implementado y me puede ayudar, verán en lenguajes como PHP puedo estar enviando en que registro va cuando subo un archivo y esto lo voy mostrando via un progressbar o un mensaje de va "x registros de 1200 del archivo miarchivo.xls", ahora en .NET MVC4 me gustaría realizar algo similar, pero no se si pueda hacer. Para recibir el archivo uso algo como esto:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file) {

  if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
    // 1 - Por aquí proceso con EPPlus
    // 2 - Aquí elimino el archivo
  }

  return Json(new { success = true, message= "Archivo almacenado de manera exitosa"},
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Todo el proceso de subir, leer el archivo para enviarlo al SQL Server y el eliminado esta ok, pero en me gustaria mostrarle al usuario que se esta procesando su archivo, que se muestre un  mensaje de "Procesando registro #XXX de 14259 registros ( miarchivo.xls )" 
Desconozco si se pueda hacer eso en MVC, si hay que hacer alguna modificacion en el Controller ó en el Entity Framework, la parte de EF la estoy manejando con Async al igual que el metodo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

De forma estandar asp.net mvc requiere de un request al servidor por parte del cliente, o sea el servidor no puede enviar datos al browser.

Pero hay una alternativa si implementas [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

Con este podrias podrias enviar mediate websocket datos al servidor informado del avance real del procesamiento del archivo para que refleje esto en el progress.

Con SignalR estarias implementando lo que se conoce como push server, para poder enviar datos al browser desde el servidor web.

Nota: no pongo un ejemplo porque hacerlo seria muy extenso, analiza si esto aplica a lo que necesitas.

Comment: voy a darle una mirada a SignalR, según yo debería de funcionar similar socket.io entonces no habría que configurar otro puerto, por que ese es el problema, abrir otro puerto en el server siempre nos ha llevado semanas para que lo autoricen jaja, en cuanto haya realizado algunas pruebas les digo como me fue :D

Comment: abrir puerto en el server ? eso no es necesario esto es transparente ya que implementa WebSocket de html5

Comment: Ok, ok nunca he usado SignalR por eso hacia mención de un puerto, por eso decía lo de Socket.io que se integra a la aplicacion, vi un ejemplo donde llaman a SignalR y es similar a Socket.io, solo resta ver que en el server 2008 jale todo bien jajaja, saludos.

Comment: pero socket.io entiendo tiene que ver con nodejs el cual ejecuta del lado del servidor, en cambio signalr se integra desde el cliente